# Configuring application port for AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I'm creating a Fargate task on AWS, which involves creating a task definition and a load balancer. I had to specify port numbers and protocols in several places:

1. When creating the task definition: I had to configure Container port and protocol.
2. When creating the service, I had to specify target group or Production listener port.
3. While creating a load balancer, I had to configure port for:

   a. Listener (which is a process that checks for connection requests, using the protocol and port that you configured).

   b. I had to create a target group and configure it (which routes requests to the targets in the target group using the specified protocol and port)

I'd like to know how all these ports are related to each other.

My container is web server that runs on port 8000. I'd like to simply have a load balancer that listens on port 80, and routes the traffic to my container that listens on port 8000. What is the association between listener and target group? Why do I have to specify target group for a service, considering that I'm already using it in a load balancer, and it's already added to a load balancer? what happens if I put them different target groups in service vs. the load balancer added to that service? If I have all these routings, why do I have to still specify Container port and protocol in the task definition?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve your desired outcome by specifying ports 4 times::

1. [Port](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup.html#cfn-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup-port) for your target group. This is **port on which your your targets (i.e. containers) receive traffic**. In your case this will be port **8000**.
2. [Port](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-listener.html#cfn-elasticloadbalancingv2-listener-port) for the load balancer listen. This is **port on which the load balancer is listening**. In you case port **80**.
3. [ContainerPort](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions-portmappings.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinition-portmappings-containerport) in **task definition**. This is the actual **port on which your app is going to listen for connection**. In your case it will be **8000**.
4. [ContainerPort](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-service-loadbalancers.html#cfn-ecs-service-loadbalancers-containerport). The port on the container to associate with the load balancer. This port **must correspond to a containerPort in the task definition** the tasks in the service are using. In your case it will be **8000**.

The [listener](http://127.0.0.1:8888/edit/ecs/04c_webapp_fargate_service_alb/templates/04c_ecs_task_def.yaml) on ALB receives traffic on port **80** and usually (you can decide what to do with it) it will forward the traffic to targets in a [target group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html). The group will consist of targets which will handle your request. In your case it will be ECS service which contains tasks listening on port **8000**. You can have many targets in a target group. In this case, a [routing algorithm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#modify-routing-algorithm) is used to chose a specific target for a given request.

p.s.
Can't answer all your sub-questions in the single SQ question at this moment. But I hope that what I could write will help you.